# klaR package and the stepclass function

Tags: r, classification, discriminant-analysis

I'm running LDA on a dataset with 250,000 observations, 2 classes and 30 variables. My goal is to create a classification model using the LDA function.

After loading my variables I receive a warning that my X's are collinear. (should this be an issue?)

I stumbled across the klaR stepclass function, which performs stepwise selection on the X's, if i'm not mistaken. My understanding is that this function should tell me what X's are needed and which aren't.

```
ldaselect <- stepclass(Label~DER_mass_MMC+DER_mass_transverse_met_lep+DER_mass_vis+
                         DER_pt_h+DER_deltaeta_jet_jet+DER_mass_jet_jet+DER_prodeta_jet_jet+
                         DER_deltar_tau_lep+DER_pt_tot+DER_sum_pt+DER_pt_ratio_lep_tau+
                         DER_met_phi_centrality+DER_lep_eta_centrality+PRI_tau_pt+
                         PRI_tau_eta+PRI_tau_phi+PRI_lep_pt+PRI_lep_eta+PRI_lep_phi+
                         PRI_met+PRI_met_phi+PRI_met_sumet+PRI_jet_num+PRI_jet_leading_pt+
                         PRI_jet_leading_eta+PRI_jet_leading_phi+PRI_jet_subleading_pt+
                         PRI_jet_subleading_eta+PRI_jet_subleading_phi+
                         PRI_jet_all_pt, data=cdata, criterion ="AS", direction="forward", method="lda")
```

I've chosen as the criterion "AS" as LDA tries to create the greatest separation with the classes.

After running the above code, it only returns one variable, "PRI_tau_pt" as the necessary X. This happens when I run forwards, backwards and both.

My understanding is that my model should only consist of an LDA of "Labels" on "PRI_tau_pt". I'm just skeptical of my understanding however, could anyone tell me if what I've done above is correct?